# Memory issue while Animating many images

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6, uianimation

I have about 272 layer of images for animating my view background. Below is a sample code on how I animate the images. But doing like this I'm getting memory issue and app crashes. Any advice?

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 272; i >=1; i--)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"layer-%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *bgImage =[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    [imagesArray addObject:bgImage];
}

[self.bgImageView setAnimationDuration:7.0f];
[self.bgImageView  setAnimationImages:imagesArray];
[self.bgImageView  startAnimating];
```

Comment: What is the size of each image?

Comment: Total size of all 272 images is around 5 mb.

Comment: Could you try comment this code and test again, I wanna make sure if this part is the reason of memory issue or another part

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I comment this code, but of course it doesnt animate :P. Also I can see the animation on simulator and seems to work for some time but on device it crashes instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Using [UIImage imageNamed:] cache the image in memory, try using [UIImage imageWithContentOfFile:]. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939722/received-memory-warning-while-using-animations-in-uiimageview-like-smyimagevie)

Comment: Tried it, but still same issue. This is the message I get from xcode  - Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Pressure

Comment: You are running out of memory because you cannot have that many images in memory at the same time under iOS (no virtual memory). You can find many solutions to the problem on stackoverflow, but basically you just cannot do what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Try release object of uiimage after adding to to array:

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 272; i >=1; i--)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"layer-%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *bgImage =[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [imagesArray addObject:bgImage];
    bgImage=nil;
    imageName=nil;
 }
    [self.bgImageView setAnimationDuration:7.0f];
    [self.bgImageView  setAnimationImages:imagesArray];
    [self.bgImageView  startAnimating];
```

Or try to declare uiimage outside loop and reuse it in each loop:

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
UIImage  *bgImage;
NSString *imageName;
for (int i = 272; i >=1; i--)
{
    imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"layer-%d.jpg", i];
    bgImage =[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [imagesArray addObject:bgImage];
 }
    [self.bgImageView setAnimationDuration:7.0f];
    [self.bgImageView  setAnimationImages:imagesArray];
    [self.bgImageView  startAnimating];
```

Comment: I don't think that will solve the problem. He is using ARC and image will be deallocated automatically